# Why do most asyncio examples use loop.run_until_complete()?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I was going through the Python documentation for `asyncio` and I'm wondering why most examples use `loop.run_until_complete()` as opposed to `Asyncio.ensure_future()`.

For example: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/asyncio-task.html

It seems `ensure_future` would be a much better way to demonstrate the advantages of non-blocking functions. `run_until_complete` on the other hand, blocks the loop like synchronous functions do.

This makes me feel like I should be using `run_until_complete` instead of a combination of `ensure_future`with `loop.run_forever()` to run multiple co-routines concurrently.

Comment: `run_until_complete` doesn't block anything. The difference between it and `run_forever` is that the loop pauses at the completion of the coroutine. The only time it will block is if your coroutine never awaits.

Comment: I wrote this http://pastebin.com/Qi8dQ3bh and it does seem to block the loop though. `do_other_things()` doesn't execute until `do_io()` is done, even though `do_io()` awaits a the sleep.

Comment: That's because nothing else has been scheduled with the loop. Try calling `loop.create_task(do_other_things())` before you call `run_forever`.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`run_until_complete` is used to run a future until it's finished. It will block the execution of code following it. It does, however, cause the event loop to run. Any futures that have been scheduled will run until the future passed to `run_until_complete` is done.

Given this example:

```
import asyncio

async def do_io():
    print('io start')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print('io end')

async def do_other_things():
    print('doing other things')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.run_until_complete(do_io())
loop.run_until_complete(do_other_things())

loop.close()
```

`do_io` will run. After it's complete, `do_other_things` will run. Your output will be:

```
io start
io end
doing other things
```

If you schedule `do_other_things` with the event loop before running `do_io`, control will switch from `do_io` to `do_other_things` when the former awaits.

```
loop.create_task(do_other_things())
loop.run_until_complete(do_io())
```

This will get you the output of:

```
doing other things
io start
io end
```

This is because `do_other_things` was scheduled before `do_io`. There are a lot of different ways to get the same output, but which one makes sense really depends on what your application actually does. So I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Do you know why I get the error "RuntimeError: This event loop is already running" when I run your code?

Comment: @Patrick did you try calling `loop.run_until_complete` from inside a function?

Comment: I realized that the problem maybe with Jupyter. It works with python code.

Comment: @Patrick (late) but I have scene this and used `loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()` (only one event loop on main is allowed though)

Comment: `get_event_loop` is deprecated : https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop

Answer (score 14):

I think most people didn't understand `create_task`.
when you `create_task` or `ensure_future`, it will be scheduled already.

```
async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(1, 'hello')) # not block here

    task2 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(2, 'world'))

    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}") # time0

    await task1 # block here!

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}") 
    
    await task2 # block here!

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

result is

```
time0 
print hello 
time0+1 
print world 
time0+2
```

but IF YOU **DON'T AWAIT task1**, do something else

```
async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(1, 'hello')) # not block here
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}") # time0
    await asyncio.sleep(2) # not await task1
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}") # time0+2
 

asyncio.run(main())
```

it will do task1 **STILL**

```
time0
print hello
time0+2
```

Comment: Nice, don't forget to  
    import asyncio  
    import time

Comment: This answer is good because it uses modern Python 3.10+ asyncio.create_task/asyncio.run. Reducing it to just those two along with asyncio.gather, asyncio.sleep and async/await themselves simplifies things a lot.